# String matching: Gets into infinte loop when using Wait(job, 'finished')

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

I am working on parallelizing String matching algorithm using MATLAB PCT. I am using createJob and several tasks where i am passing the text to be searched, pattern and other parameters. I get the following error. Any idea. The boyer_horsepool function the tasks are targetted looks fine.

```
Error using parallel.Job/fetchOutputs (line 677)


An error occurred during execution of Task with ID 1.

Error in stringmatch (line 42)


matches = fetchOutputs(job1);

Caused by:

    Error using feval

    Undefined function handle.
```

Code

```
% create the job 

parallel.defaultClusterProfile('local');
cluster = parcluster(); 
job1 = createJob(cluster);

% create the tasks

for index = 1: num_tasks

    ret = createTask(job1, @boyer_horsepool, 1, {haystack, needle, nlength, startValues(index), endValues(index)});

    fprintf('For index %d the crateTask value is ?\n',index); 

    disp(class(ret));

    %disp(ret);

end

% Submit and wait for the results
submit(job1);       
wait(job1);

% Report the number of matches    
matches = fetchOutputs(job1);

delete(job1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I could be wrong, but it looks like your syntax is fine...

I think the issue is that it's not recognizing boyer_horsepool as a function. It's hard to do anything further without a bit more context. Try moving that function into the same .m file, and double check the spelling and argument count.

Also, try getAllOutputArguments(job1). It's a long shot, but it might work.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly its not identifying the boyer_horsepool function. I have placed all the functions locally. Function call made outside i.e. not within the createTask() are working all fine. Anyways i will try working on your lead also.